# Firebase security rule allow access only to nested item

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm following the suggested data model from [this tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/reddit-style-upvoting-in-angular-4-and-firebase-nosql/) for counting upvotes in a firebase database:

```
-| upvotes
    -| itemId
      -| userId: number
```

This works fine but the problem I'm encountering is how to allow users to only be able to update their own upvote. If I use something like this:

```js
match /votes/{id}  {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth != null;
  match /{uid} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid;
  }
}
```

Then any authenticated user can edit the entire vote entry. But if I try to restrict to just the /uid match:

```js
match /votes/{id}  {
  allow read: if true;
  match /{uid} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid;
  }
}
```

Then I get insufficient permissions when I try to alter the record. Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: You can't target individual fields with a `match` wildcard.  You can only match entire documents, then use the matched documents fields within the `allow` rules to determine who can do what with that matched document.  You might be helped by reviewing the examples in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Comment: I will point out also that what you're showing here in the question is difficult to work with because you have both "upvotes" and "votes" as names of collections, and also "uid" and "userId" as the apparent name of the field.  It will be easier if you make sure they are consistent and show an actual document of data that you're working with.  It will also be helpful to see your client code as well, since your code must match your rules, or it won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this where you have mixed private and public access, you might find it easier to break apart the `write` rule into its components: `create`, `update` and `delete`.

Using the features of the [`Map`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map), [`MapDiff`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) and [`List`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) interfaces in your security rules allows you to implement the following restrictions:

```json
match /votes/{id} {
  // anyone can read
  allow read: if true;

  // Anyone can create a new vote pool, as long as they mark
  // themselves the owner first, they can optionally cast their
  // own vote at the same time.
  allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ownerId
    && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["ownerId", request.auth.uid]);

  // Anyone can update the vote pool, but they can only change data
  // under their own userId (such as adding/updating/removing their
  // vote). Even owners can only update their own vote once created.
  allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly([request.auth.uid]);;

  // only the owner can delete a vote pool
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;
}
```

**Important:** These rules do not currently restrict *what* is written under the user's ID. With the current rules, a malicious user could write large amounts of data under that key. It is up to you to decide what can and can't be written there.

**Note:** You may want to adjust the above rules so that you can give the vote pool a title. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader on how to make sure it is provided at creation with a proper value. You can optionally make the title editable, but that should be discouraged as the results can be viewed differently depending on the title change. You can also implement the ability for the owner to lock the vote pool and prevent further changes.